# Smallest Unique subsequence from list of string

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get only the smallest unique subsequence from list of string. For example:

1. [1,11,111,12,13] -  I want to get only the first value i.e. 1
2. [11,12,13,131,141,14,111]  - I want values - 11,12,13,14 only.

I am trying but facing issue to get the exact value. **Values** is the collection of element.

```
var str = new List<string>();
string[] str1 = values.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ToArray();

foreach(var s in str1)
{
    if (str.count() < 1)
        str.Add(s);
    else
    {
        int count = str.Count;
        for (int i=0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if (s.StartsWith(str[i]))
            {
                break;
            }
            str.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That won't even compile, because `str` is a `List` and lists don't have a `IsNullOrEmpty()`

Comment: You might want to use a [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Comment: @derpirscher Its complies successfully, but i need to modify logic in else part.

Comment: @juharr sorry didn't understood you comment.

Comment: @gauravprasad Follow the link to an explaination of what a Trie is.

Comment: @gauravprasad `IsNullOrEmpty()` is it your custom extension method?

Comment: If you're dealing with numbers, why are you using strings in the first place?

Comment: @41686d6564 Because checking the prefix for a string is proably easier than for a number

Comment: @huMptyduMpty no its of collections generic.

Comment: @derpirscher "11,12,13,14" looks like a numerical sequence to me. The OP's description is about it one thing and the code appears to be doing a different thing. The question needs more details.

Comment: @41686d6564 yes. But the goal seems to be, that if `1` is contained in that sequence, all numbers "starting" with `1` should be filtered out (ie for instance 11,12,13, or 111, or 123456789). And thats easier to check on strings than on numbers. Especially if you have a sequence like "1134, 1135, 1136, 1134567", where "1134567" should be filtered out. And if the code already worked as OP wanted it, he probably wouldn have asked. And generally with such question I tend to favor the description of the behaviour over the actual code

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, if the collection has "1134, 1135, 1136, 1134567" - the result should be 1134, 1135,1136 and not 1134567 as it contains 1134.

Comment: You are going to need to update your question with a better description of your goal.  In particular, defining what you mean by _smallest unique subsequence_.  Neither your examples nor what you've said over the course of several comments matched what I understood from that description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. But you were adding `s` before you checked all elements already contained in the set. And the check for "still empty result" isn't really needed.

If you can use Linq, the following should work. See code for explanaition

```
public static List<string> prefixFree(List<string> words) {
    //order the words by their length
    var w = words.OrderBy(x => x.Length);

    var result = new List<string>();

    //for each of the words check
    foreach (var s in w) {
        //if it starts with any of the words already in the result
        if (!result.Any(x => s.StartsWith((x))))
            //if no match is found, add it to the result
            result.Add(s);
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This Works as expected. Thanks!